# Can't get around the System Update error message booting Ubuntu on MacOs

Tags: 18.04, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, usb

So here is the situation :

I want to dual boot Ubuntu on my Macbookpro (September 2019) and I keep getting this error message in the boot assistant manager telling me a system update is required to use this startup disk.

So I was on Mojave 10.14, I formated the 16 Gb usb drive and used Bootable Drive Maker (Later I also tried with Etcher and a third one than I don't remember the name) to put the iso on the drive. Then it took me hours to be able to partition the Mac HD because it was impossible to use the diskutility. I finally did everything in terminal :

- create 2 partitions, one for UBUNTU of 60 Gb and one for the SWAP of 33 Gb
- Converted iso to img.dmg. and put that on the usb drive with that sweet message telling me that the drive is not readable by the computer which is perfect

Just FYI I tried that many times with different formats for the drive : APFS, MacOS extended journalized...

Then I reboot with option and get the choice between Mac HD or EFI Boot, I choose EFI Boot and get the apple and loading screen until the boot assistant manager gives me this message telling me a system update is required to use this startup disk. I can choose update or startup disk. Start up disk gives me this screen where I can only see the MacHD

So I go for update... apple, loading and it reboots normally (Tried to do the update multiple times). I restart and try again to get to the same screen for ever.

So I went for the last OS : Catalina.

After that, I restarted in recovery mode because I was sure it was these security settings in the Startup disk utilities, removed everything and allowing to boot from ext. drive.

Tried again, same screen

Tried multiple other things, same screen.

Why the heck can't I boot from this usb drive?

It is the last Ubuntu (18.04.3) and the last Catalina 10.15.2

I found something on a forum, someone saying she could get it to work with formatting the drive in APFS and it worked for other people so I tried that again. Same screen...

Please help !

EDIT : tried the usb drive on my PC and it worked perfectly. I was able to install Ubuntu on my windows PC.
As someone told me, it could be something with the mac EFI not allowing to bot from my 3 years old usb drive. I tried with another drive but older. Same result.

How to tell the BIOS equivalent on Mac to tell it to boot anyway from the drive ?

EDIT 2 : Finally made it clicking the full security in the startup disk utility and clicking "no security" back. Then I chose the other efi boot and it worked. I did that 4 days ago with no success. I have no idea how I did that otherwise. Now new problem : Ubuntu won't see my internal hard drive, neither my external. It sees the booting USB drive only. New Macbook pros are some work...

If anyone has an idea... Please!

Comment: Nice post.  Trying to help get this viewed by many people for help.  I believe you you should edit the tags, remove the dual boot bit since that will be obvious from the details on the Mac then add the OS version you are trying to install [18.04], maybe remove mac tag and use [installation] Be patient people will help soon. My suggestions are not required by any means, you have a good post, I'm just adding what I would do in your situation.

Comment: Thanx ! Let's do that ! :)

Comment: Did you manage to get it installed? I want to do the same

Comment: Your "EDIT 2" worked for me. You should repost as an answer. The first EFI drive kept saying, "A software update is required to use this startup disk." I hadn't thought to try the second one because the tutorial I was following said to select the first. But the second one worked.

Comment: A related issue on another forum, says that mac younger than 2019 doesn't support any other system except for widows:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389265/how-to-fix-efi-boot-software-update-is-required-for-this-disk-when-trying-to-b, also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400009/a-software-update-is-required-to-use-this-startup-disk-does-not-update